# Shift wise punch get wrong output on particular value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Based on following shift need expected output . 
Help me to sort out this.

Employee punching raw data stored in below table

Trnevents:

```
  Emp_Reader_Id            DT                Belongs_to
        91         2019-12-15 08:08:03.000   2019-12-15
        91         2019-12-14 20:02:24.000   2019-12-14
        91         2019-12-14 08:03:55.000   2019-12-14
        91         2019-12-14 00:01:31.000   2019-12-14
        91         2019-12-13 16:10:08.000   2019-12-13
        91         2019-12-12 20:06:37.000   2019-12-12
        91         2019-12-12 08:05:42.000   2019-12-12
        91         2019-12-11 20:07:37.000   2019-12-11
        91         2019-12-10 20:11:02.000   2019-12-10
        91         2019-12-10 08:03:05.000   2019-12-10
        91         2019-12-09 20:08:03.000   2019-12-09
        91         2019-12-09 08:06:18.000   2019-12-09
        91         2019-12-08 20:01:58.000   2019-12-08
        91         2019-12-08 08:02:34.000   2019-12-08
        91         2019-12-08 00:07:02.000   2019-12-08
        91         2019-12-07 16:01:42.000   2019-12-07
        91         2019-12-07 08:04:41.000   2019-12-07
        91         2019-12-06 20:14:08.000   2019-12-06
        91         2019-12-06 08:06:33.000   2019-12-06
        91         2019-12-05 20:01:06.000   2019-12-05
        91         2019-12-05 09:06:46.000   2019-12-05
        91         2019-12-04 20:00:23.000   2019-12-04
        91         2019-12-04 11:19:23.000   2019-12-04
        91         2019-12-03 20:03:01.000   2019-12-03
        91         2019-12-03 08:05:59.000   2019-12-03
        91         2019-12-02 20:02:21.000   2019-12-02
        91         2019-12-02 09:09:35.000   2019-12-02
        91         2019-12-01 19:56:47.000   2019-12-01
        91         2019-12-01 08:08:11.000   2019-12-01
```

Employee shift scheduled day wise in a month like below

Shift_schedule

```
  emp_reader_id month_no    year_no 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
          91       12        2019   14  14  14  14  14  14  18  13  13  13  13  13  13  18  14
```

Shift

```
shift_id    shift_title
  14            Night
  18            Regular
```

Shift details as below

Shift_days

```
shift_id    day_id  day_start_time  day_end_time    night_shift isOffday
  18          1          0.00          0.00            0           1
  18          2          0.00          0.00            0           1
  18          3          0.00          0.00            0           1
  18          4          0.00          0.00            0           1
  18          5          0.00          0.00            0           1
  18          6          0.00          0.00            0           1
  18          7          0.00          0.00            0           1
  14          1          20.00         4.00            1           0
  14          2          20.00         4.00            1           0
  14          3          20.00         4.00            1           0
  14          4          20.00         4.00            1           0
  14          5          20.00         4.00            1           0
  14          6          20.00         4.00            1           0
  14          7          20.00         4.00            1           0
```

Expected output :

```
   emp_reader_id    in_time out_time
      91    2019-12-14 08:03:51.000 2019-12-14 20:02:24.000
      91    2019-12-13 16:10:08.000 2019-12-14 00:01:31.000
      91    2019-12-12 08:05:42.000 2019-12-12 20:06:37.000
      91    2019-12-11 20:07:37.000 2019-12-11 20:07:37.000
      91    2019-12-10 08:03:05.000 2019-12-10 20:11:02.000
      91    2019-12-09 08:06:18.000 2019-12-09 20:08:03.000
      91    2019-12-08 08:02:02.000 2019-12-08 20:01:58.000
      91    2019-12-07 16:01:42.000 2019-12-08 00:07:02.000
      91    2019-12-06 20:14:08.000 2019-12-07 08:04:42.000
      91    2019-12-05 20:01:06.000 2019-12-06 08:06:33.000
      91    2019-12-04 20:00:23.000 2019-12-05 09:06:46.000
      91    2019-12-03 20:03:01.000 2019-12-04 11:19:23.000
      91    2019-12-02 20:02:21.000 2019-12-03 08:05:59.000
      91    2019-12-01 19:56:47.000 2019-12-02 09:09:35.000
```

I tried to get result as above fine but on leave days its not proper

```
          DECLARE @TempTable as Table
           (emp_reader_id nvarchar(50),DT datetime,ExitDateTime datetime,Belongs_to date,seconds bigint )

                ;

            WITH  Level1
              AS (
                    SELECT  A.emp_reader_id,
                             CASE WHEN  A.EventCatId=1 and  (A.DT between dateadd(minute,-0, B.break_start_time) and  B.break_end_time)
                                                     THEN B.break_start_time
                                                WHEN  A.EventCatId=0 and (A.DT between B.break_start_time and B.break_end_time) 
                                                     THEN  B.break_end_time
                                           ELSE A.DT END AS 
                                           DT
                     ,A.EventCatId
                     ,A.Belongs_to
                     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY A.Belongs_to,A.emp_reader_id  ORDER BY DT ) AS RowNum 
                   FROM dbo.trnevents A  
                   left JOIN @TempProcessTable B on A.emp_reader_id = B.emp_reader_id and A.Belongs_to=B.att_date
                   where A.Belongs_to between @start_date and @end_date and B.emp_reader_id in (select emp_reader_id from employee where company_id=@company_id)

                 )
               , 
              LEVEL2
              AS (-- find the last and next event type for each row 
                   SELECT A.emp_reader_id,A.DT , A.EventCatId ,COALESCE(LastVal.EventCatId, 10) AS LastEvent,
                                                            COALESCE(NextVal.EventCatId, 10) AS NextEvent ,A.Belongs_to
                   FROM Level1 A 
                           LEFT JOIN Level1 LastVal 
                              ON A.emp_reader_id = LastVal.emp_reader_id and  A.Belongs_to=LastVal.Belongs_to
                                 AND A.RowNum - 1 = LastVal.RowNum 
                           LEFT JOIN Level1 NextVal 
                              ON A.emp_reader_id = NextVal.emp_reader_id and  A.Belongs_to=NextVal.Belongs_to
                                 AND A.RowNum + 1 = NextVal.RowNum 
                 )
                 , 
               Level3 
               AS (-- reapply row numbers to row-eliminated set 
                   SELECT  emp_reader_id ,DT , EventCatId ,LastEvent ,NextEvent ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY emp_reader_id 
                                                                                                       ORDER BY DT ) AS RowNBr 
                                                                                                       ,Belongs_to
                   FROM Level2 
                      WHERE   NOT ( EventCatId = 0 
                                   AND LastEvent = 0 
                                  ) 
                             AND NOT ( EventCatId = 1 
                                      AND NextEvent = 1 
                                      ) 
                             AND NOT ( EventCatId = 0 
                                      AND NextEvent = 10 
                                      ) 
                             AND NOT ( EventCatId = 1 
                                      AND LastEvent = 10 
                                      ) 
                      )
                      , 
               Level4
               AS (-- pair enter and exit rows. 
                   SELECT A.emp_reader_id , A.DT ,B.DT AS ExitDateTime ,A.Belongs_to
                      FROM Level3 A 
                            INNER JOIN Level3 B ON A.emp_reader_id = B.emp_reader_id and A.Belongs_to=B.Belongs_to
                                             AND A.RowNBr + 1 = B.RowNBr 
                       and A.EventCatId = 0 
                             AND B.EventCatId = 1
                       )
```

Comment: We can't see your code, or the results you describe as "not proper". We don't know what the logic behind the missing code is, or why the missing results are "not proper". There's really not much we can do here unless you edit this question to include the relevant details of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to approach the classification of events (trnevents) from a different angle.

Unpivot the Shift_schedule and you get a set of days (call it ReaderShiftDays) per month for a specific reader.
In turn, joining ReaderShiftDays & Shift_Days the result will be the definition/attributes (day, night, leave) of each ReaderShiftDay.
Finally, (left?) joining with Trnevents (on emp_reader_id & ReaderShiftDays.Day = day(Trnevents.DT) and you get for each trnevent the actual attributes of the shift (placing the trnevent in the slot of the plan/shift).
Knowing the attribute for each trnevent, you could flag it as belonging to previous or calculate the adjusted start date/belongsto (if any).
Grouping all this by reader, shift day and flag/startdate/belongsto and you get the min&max (start&end) DT (of trnevent)

```
CREATE TABLE TrnEvents
(
    Emp_Reader_Id INT,
    DT DATETIME,
    BelongsTo DATE
);

INSERT INTO TrnEvents(Emp_Reader_Id, DT, BelongsTo)
VALUES 

(91,'2019-12-15 08:08:03.000','2019-12-15'),
(91,'2019-12-14 20:02:24.000','2019-12-14'),
(91,'2019-12-14 08:03:55.000','2019-12-14'),
(91,'2019-12-14 00:01:31.000','2019-12-14'),
(91,'2019-12-13 16:10:08.000','2019-12-13'),
(91,'2019-12-12 20:06:37.000','2019-12-12'),
(91,'2019-12-12 08:05:42.000','2019-12-12'),
(91,'2019-12-11 20:07:37.000','2019-12-11'),
(91,'2019-12-10 20:11:02.000','2019-12-10'),
(91,'2019-12-10 08:03:05.000','2019-12-10'),
(91,'2019-12-09 20:08:03.000','2019-12-09'),
(91,'2019-12-09 08:06:18.000','2019-12-09'),
(91,'2019-12-08 20:01:58.000','2019-12-08'),
(91,'2019-12-08 08:02:34.000','2019-12-08'),
(91,'2019-12-08 00:07:02.000','2019-12-08'),
(91,'2019-12-07 16:01:42.000','2019-12-07'),
(91,'2019-12-07 08:04:41.000','2019-12-07'),
(91,'2019-12-06 20:14:08.000','2019-12-06'),
(91,'2019-12-06 08:06:33.000','2019-12-06'),
(91,'2019-12-05 20:01:06.000','2019-12-05'),
(91,'2019-12-05 09:06:46.000','2019-12-05'),
(91,'2019-12-04 20:00:23.000','2019-12-04'),
(91,'2019-12-04 11:19:23.000','2019-12-04'),
(91,'2019-12-03 20:03:01.000','2019-12-03'),
(91,'2019-12-03 08:05:59.000','2019-12-03'),
(91,'2019-12-02 20:02:21.000','2019-12-02'),
(91,'2019-12-02 09:09:35.000','2019-12-02'),
(91,'2019-12-01 19:56:47.000','2019-12-01'),
(91,'2019-12-01 08:08:11.000','2019-12-01');
GO


CREATE TABLE Shift_schedule
(
    emp_reader_id int,
    month_no smallint,
    year_no smallint,
    [1] tinyint,
    [2] tinyint,
    [3] tinyint,
    [4] tinyint,
    [5] tinyint,    
    [6] tinyint,    
    [7] tinyint,    
    [8] tinyint,
    [9] tinyint,
    [10] tinyint,
    [11] tinyint,
    [12] tinyint,   
    [13] tinyint,   
    [14] tinyint,
    [15] tinyint

)

INSERT INTO Shift_schedule
(
emp_reader_id, month_no, year_no, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15]
)
VALUES (91, 12, 2019, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 18, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 18, 14);
GO


CREATE TABLE Shift_days
(
    shift_id int,
    day_id tinyint,
    day_start_time time,
    day_end_time time,
    night_shift bit,
    isOffday bit
)

INSERT INTO Shift_days
VALUES
  (18,1,'00:00','00:00',0,1),
  (18,2,'00:00','00:00',0,1),
  (18,3,'00:00','00:00',0,1),
  (18,4,'00:00','00:00',0,1),
  (18,5,'00:00','00:00',0,1),
  (18,6,'00:00','00:00',0,1),
  (18,7,'00:00','00:00',0,1),
  (14,1,'20:00','04:00',1,0),
  (14,2,'20:00','04:00',1,0),
  (14,3,'20:00','04:00',1,0),
  (14,4,'20:00','04:00',1,0),
  (14,5,'20:00','04:00',1,0),
  (14,6,'20:00','04:00',1,0),
  (14,7,'20:00','04:00',1,0);

GO


SELECT *,
    MIN(DT) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_reader_id, month_no, year_no, AdjustedBelongsTo) AS FromDateTime,
    MAX(DT) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_reader_id, month_no, year_no, AdjustedBelongsTo) AS ToDateTime
    --MIN(DT) AS FromDateTIme, MAX(DT) AS ToDateTime
FROM
(
    SELECT *, 
        CASE 
            --better adjust the slot/shiftday instead of belongsto
            --add logic of handling event.DTs here
            WHEN (night_shift = 1 AND (DT = MinDT OR MinDT = MaxDT)) THEN DATEADD(day, -1, BelongsTo)
            WHEN (night_shift = 0 AND( DT = MaxDT OR MinDT = MaxDT)) THEN DATEADD(day, 1, BelongsTo)
            ELSE BelongsTo END AS AdjustedBelongsTo
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            rsd.emp_reader_id, rsd.month_no, rsd.year_no, rsd.ShiftId, rsd.ShiftDay, 
            --shift attribs
            sd.night_shift, sd.isOffday, sd.day_start_time, sd.day_end_time,
            --event
            e.DT, e.BelongsTo,
            --ordinal or min/max (what about 3 or more events per day?)
            --ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.BelongsTo ORDER BY DT) AS DayEventOrdinal,
            MIN(e.DT) OVER(PARTITION BY rsd.emp_reader_id, rsd.month_no, rsd.year_no, rsd.ShiftId, rsd.ShiftDay, e.BelongsTo) AS MinDT,
            MAX(e.DT) OVER(PARTITION BY rsd.emp_reader_id, rsd.month_no, rsd.year_no, rsd.ShiftId, rsd.ShiftDay, e.BelongsTo) AS MaxDT
            --,*
        FROM
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM Shift_schedule
            UNPIVOT
            (
                ShiftId for ShiftDay IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15])
            ) AS unp
        ) AS rsd --ReaderShiftDays
        LEFT JOIN Shift_days AS sd ON rsd.ShiftId = sd.shift_id AND DATEPART(weekday, DATEFROMPARTS(rsd.year_no, rsd.month_no, rsd.ShiftDay)) = sd.day_id
        LEFT JOIN TrnEvents AS e ON rsd.emp_reader_id = e.Emp_Reader_Id AND DATEFROMPARTS(rsd.year_no , rsd.month_no, rsd.ShiftDay) = CAST(e.DT AS DATE)
    ) AS prep       
) AS adjusted
--GROUP BY emp_reader_id, month_no, year_no, AdjustedBelongsTo
ORDER BY emp_reader_id, month_no, year_no, AdjustedBelongsTo;
```